# How to update data copy in next table using angular js

Tags: json, angularjs

Hi i m using in my project a simple functionality.

i have a table and some data is fetch data in json file .

Data is coming and if i click to name than edit mode is on if i blur than hide the edit mode and show the view mode is fine i have do this .

now i have a update button if i click to this button than only updated data in insert next row how to do this please check to this and help me .

My code is this

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCntrl', function($scope, $http){
 $http.get('js/list.json').success(function(data){
  $scope.emplyeList = data;
 });    


 $scope.updateSec= function(employe){
  alert("Rohit");
 }
});
```

```css
.click{

    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
   .normal-table{
    width: 50%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   .normal-table th{
    border: solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
   }

   .normal-table td{
    border: solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">

 
 <body>

  <table class="normal-table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Address</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="employe in emplyeList">
    <td>
     <div ng-show="!data" ng-click="data=true" class="click">{{employe.name}}</div>
     <div ng-show="data"><input ng-blur="data=false" type="text" ng-model="employe.name" /></div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <div ng-show="!data">{{employe.ID}}</div>
     <div ng-show="data"><input type="text" ng-model="employe.ID" /></div>
    </td>
    <td>
     <div ng-show="!data">{{employe.add}}</div>
     <div ng-show="data"><input type="text" ng-model="employe.add" /></div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
     <button ng-click="updateSec(employe)">Update</button>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="updatEm in employe">
    <td>{{updatEm.name}}</td>
    <td>{{updatEm.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{updatEm.add}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
   </div>
```

My Json file is

```
[
    {"name":"Rohit", "ID":"5Rt", "add":"Delhi"},
    {"name":"Kiran", "ID":"4Kn", "add":"UP"},
    {"name":"Abhay", "ID":"3Ay", "add":"HR"},
    {"name":"Rahul", "ID":"2Rl", "add":"UK"}
]
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: if i update my table data than i click to update button those data has been updated those data show in next tr

Comment: @Satpal yes this is i want to this but here is only one row show if i edit two row than click to update only show to last update i want to show all update data .

Comment: @Satpal Thanks to give me answer but i want to only those list show those i m update . now you post your code i accept it .

if i want to update only two row than click to update than show only two row in bootm row

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Lzf4a4sj/ hope it works as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*HTML*

```
<tr ng-repeat="employe in emplyeList" ng-click="updateSec(employe)">
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <button ng-click="showData()">Update</button>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr ng-if="showEmployee" ng-repeat="employe in modifiedEmplyee">
    <td>{{employe.name}}</td>
    <td>{{employe.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{employe.add}}</td>
</tr>
```

*Script*

```
//Display list
$scope.showEmployee = false;    

//Create an array to hold updated employee
$scope.modifiedEmplyee = [];

//Set updated field to identify updated employee
$scope.updateSec = function (employe) {
    employe.updated = true;
    $scope.showEmployee = false;        
}

//Show data and copy modilfied list
$scope.showData = function () {
    $scope.showEmployee = true;
    $scope.modifiedEmplyee = [];

    for(var i = 0; i< $scope.emplyeList.length; i++)
    {
        var emp = $scope.emplyeList[i];
        if(emp.updated && emp.updated == true){
             $scope.modifiedEmplyee.push(emp);
        }           
    }        
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Lzf4a4sj/)